# How to get Funding for My startup Idea

Tags: startup

I have been looking out to asking the right person, only I don't know how to ask, hence I decided to make it an open question here and see who can be of help somehow.

So i have always wanted to run my own startup. A payment service startup where one can initiate payments for Africans (Apparently, I am African and we need some form of cross border payments too down here) So i decided to ask this. What's the best way to get funding for a project i want to turn into a Business? I am a developer (Software Developer / Mobile app Developer) and I also know some UI/UX design as well. What is the best way to get started? Do I need to come up with an Android APK or is a prototype with figma or Adobe XD to show what I can do? Please advice me in this case, I need some guidance here somehow

Comment: Not really answering the core part of your question, but a payments platform is way more than just having an app. There are backend servers to write, integration with the prevailing financial systems, and most importantly regulatory and legal issues. Just to further my point, PayPal is currently supported either partially or fully in 50 African countries. It's likely there are significant reasons why they don't fully operate in every African state.

Comment: You are too ambitious. Start from your own country first. After few years, if successful then cross the border. Learn how to walk before you run.

Comment: Determine what the secret sauce is going to be.  How does this differ from the existing global money transfers solutions currently on the market.  Focus on that secret sauce while you do what the answer below suggested and do market research. There must be a reason someone hasn’t done your idea.

Comment: A country tag could be helpful, due to cultural/legal differences. In my country for example one can actually get help from the government, this might not be applicable to you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is off topic.

Comment: You may get some answers for this on https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ but you would have to reword the question a little to make it on-topic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a business portfolio including images, cost breakdown, logistics, strategy, mission, your background, print it on SquareSpace free in HTML format and in PDF to post with emails, do a video presentation in 4k describing the PDF as well as you can, post it on YT when your project starts.

Contact companies that can sponsor you, if the company has some kind of altruistic person, or try patreon to say you wish to start a business, find buyers through PR, try a crowdfunding campaign.

Work every day contacting people, companies, looking for new communications opportunities, sending around your video, portfolio, build an email list through squarespace (small business accounts gives you 3 emails, infinite subscribers), do original and artistic publicity stunts dressed up asking for help to create awareness. :)

Read up about your sector, it's called microfinancing and micro financial services, there are many startups and lessons to learn in that industry.

good luck

Comment: Now thats more like it. I will work with this as well.

Comment: If you want free images to use on commercial work, there's some on Pexels.com and SVGfree! cheers for the upvote!

Comment: Why in 4k? Surely any anything above 720p with correct lighting is *just* as good? Why waste such money for a youtube ad?

Answer (score 15):

You will need some sort of proof of concept for your idea. A business plan.

A payment software for example is *not* about the UX/UI or the coding. Any university dropout can program the UI for a payment service.

The question is how do you actually move the money? Do you partner with a bank? Do you become a bank yourself? Are there are laws and regulations for banks in your country and internationally?

How do you position yourself in contrast to the existing providers of such services? What can you do that they don't? Why would people use your product? What if they abuse your product? How do you make sure they don't and what do you do if they break your security? Will you be liable? Are there laws and regulations for that?

So... those are the questions you need to have answers to. Coders are a dime a dozen, you want to found a *company*, a *business*, you need to think in terms of business, not code.

Comment: this is looking good, So in response, i want to ask you, is something like a digital bank for crossborder payments a good idea?

Comment: Let's put it this way... if the border you want to cross was too much effort for PayPal or Stripe, what makes you think you can do it? I mean maybe you can, but first you need to find out what you would need to do to make it happen. I don't know. I just know it's pretty complicated, because moving money around is subject to all kinds of laws and regulations, nationally and internationally.

Comment: Good and well explained. Now see where i am coming from, for something like a digital bank, in Nigeria for instance receiving money from overseas especially for remote workers unless done thru Worldremit or WU is a challenge. So i was thinking of having something that enables payouts in local currency. Other than the foreign payments. Would utilise the api from https://xe.com to make the exchange and payout in foreign currency...

The same goes to other african nations... thats what I mean. All they need do, is sign up for an account via the mobile app or online.

Comment: Well, there probably is a reasons for the fact that it's that much of a challenge. Start really slow and work on a few busness cases. Alice wants to send her nephew Bob 100$ for his Birthday. How would that work with your app. I'm not talking coding or UI, I'm talking Alice having 100$ in their hand and Bob living in another country. How do they get there? Who will take the 100$ from Alice, and who will give Bob 100$? (pick a currency of your choice, it doesn't really matter).

Comment: so finalizing, after drafting my business plans, Do i include the prototype? UI/UX views etc or the apk together? @nvoigt

Comment: As I said, the main problem your company has to solve is moving money legally. You need to show you have a plan for *that* to attract investors. The actual app... is an afterthought. any professional programmer could do that, you could even just hire one. Showing an app would just show that you did not understand the magnitude of the problem. It would be like showing people the flag you want to plant on the moon... nice try, but it would be more important to explain how you want to get there.

Comment: Thank you. I think Its clear Now. Let me get to the Business Plan. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Ginger you run an immediate danger of your bank accounts being frozen and closed as soon as you register the business. Almost all banks worldwide will dot allow you banking services, so you need to solve cash handling begore anything else.

Comment: @Kilisi How you mean?

Comment: Banks take a de-risking approach to the sort of service you want to provide. So they'll freeze any existing accounts then close them, And deny new ones. Look up derisking. Moving money cross border used to be easy, now people are resorting to things like crypto tokens and blockchains etc,. ... which sort of work, but are risky and also are denied bank accounts many places

Comment: @Ginger I feel you severely underestimate the legalities involved. It's probably going to take you several years of research for you to understand what is required to make this all happen. And that doesn't even solve the problem of selling this idea to other people. For example, if terrorists use your app to transfer money, do you understand that YOU can go to jail. Some countries in Africa even have the death penalty for supporting terrorism. How will you check and manage this? Have you thought about it?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie hmm, this part i have to put a major concern, i have to think about this part deeply.

Comment: It's not impossible, I've done it. But the actual development is the easiest part. It's worthless if you don't know exactly what you need to develop into your program. Once you have it covered though you're bulletproof. in legal terms.

Comment: @Ginger I had a roommate in college, and he always joked that the best way to "fix" his credit score would be to own a bank.  Later I worked for JPMorgan.  I can state that there are laws in nearly every country that define "banking services" and then indicate that if you provide those services, you must have permission to provide them from the government.  This permission will eventually require you to follow other laws.  Just tracking and proving you're following all laws is as complicated as the problem you're trying to solve.  These laws protect people.  Look them up or go to jail.

Comment: https://www.federalreserve.gov/faqs/banking_12779.htm is the "starting page" for starting a US bank.  I imagine that your country has something similar, or maybe their regulations are printed in book form.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are a software developer (so am I) so you are probably thinking of what you need to write.  That's not as important in starting a business as you think, even if the business relies critically on software.

https://www.sba.gov/business-guide/plan-your-business/write-your-business-plan

The first part of starting your business is to do some planning.  This basically looks like "how we are going to make money"; but, it is done in a much finer grain detail than you are dealing with.

Let me give you an example, I came up with a brilliant idea on how to save money on heating water; and, I also had a pretty good idea of how much money it would cost to build the prototype.  As I was working out my business plan, I realized that my plan ran directly in contrast with the law, because of a water heater health-related issues that I knew nothing about.  If I skimped on doing a full business plan, I would have invested heavily in a startup that was guaranteed to fail.

An older example, I wanted to open a computer service shop.  In doing that shop's business plan, I realized that small computer repair shops had very high overheads (cost of keeping the shop open) in my area, and that if I opened it, I would effectively be working 12 hours a day and earning less than half my (then) current salary.

Good business plans do more than detail who their customers are, they also detail how many of them there are, how many of them you're likely to attract in the first year, how likely you'll be able to keep them happy (support / service), and roughly what your expenses and income would look like.  If you can't even estimate that, odds are you don't know enough to open a successful business.  Yes, there are rare businesses that succeed without these details, but there are hundreds more that fail.

You probably know how to design your software.  If you're opening a business, you need to put that kind of effort and dedication into designing your business too.